# Inverse of the System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo() Method

Tags: c#, geolocation, geospatial, windows-phone-7

I have an instance of [GeoCoordinate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) from the [Bing Maps Silverlight control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.maps%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). I'm trying to draw a line on the map control at a given bearing.

My current approach is to:

1. Figure out a distance suitable for the current ZoomLevel.
2. Combine this distance with the bearing to find the corresponding destination GeoCoordinate.
3. Add a MapPolyline from the origin GeoCoordinate to the destination GeoCoordinate in a MapLayer.

The [GetDistanceTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) method performs the reverse operation, but I can't find a method that takes the bearing and distance and results in a GeoCoordinate.

**Is there a method I can call with the origin GeoCoordinate, bearing and distance that will find the destination GeoCoordinate?**

Comment: My current approach of drawing a line for the bearing seems to work well at close in Zoom Levels. However, as the Map zooms out what was a  bearing of 101.64 degrees switches from being just below east to just above it. Turns out over larger distances bearings vary significantly - http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#bearing.

Answer (score 1):

As a stub answer, lets assume that the framework doesn't currently have a method for finding a GeoCoordinate given:

- A origin GeoCoordinate,
- a bearing,
- and distance to travel.

In this case the [C# Geodesy Library for GPS – Vincenty’s Formulae](http://www.gavaghan.org/blog/free-source-code/geodesy-library-vincentys-formula/) is a good place to get code to do the calculation. I haven't yet figured out which reference ellipsoid model to use so that the GetDistanceTo() method can reverse the operation.

I'm still wondering if there is any built in support for solving what I now know is referred to as the [First geodetic problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#First_geodetic_problem).